# How can I type a "<" or a ">" in my HTML paragraph?

Tags: html

I want to write larger than or smaller than symbols inside my html paragraph, for example:

```
<p>
    15 > 13
</p>
```

I want the paragraph to show `15 > 13` but it's invalid syntax.
How can I fix that? Thanks

Comment: I guess you're looking for `&gt;` ?

Comment: Looking up escape characters will lead you in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use HTML entities.

```
<p>
    15 &gt; 13
</p>
```

`&gt;` is `>` and `&lt;` is `<`.

There are many others you should learn.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity

Answer (score 1):

`>` is written using `&gt;` and `<` with `&lt;`

```
<p>
    15 &gt; 13
</p>
```

You can see a [full list](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/named-characters.html#named-character-references) of available named character references. The general pattern is an ampersand, followed by some name, ended with a semicolon.